# Using truth tables, verify that the contrapositive and original statement are logically equivalent.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do I approach this? I understand how to construct a truth table, such as this one:

[image]

However, is this enough to prove that they are equivalent statements?

Comment: You should now write a few words explaining **why** that truth table proves that the contrapositive and the original statement are logically equivalent.  Also, even better, delete the parts of the truth table that are not relevant to this question.

Comment: Yes, if you show that they are the same the two statements are then equivalent.

Comment: Two functions are equivalent if they produce same output on all inputs.

Comment: Yes, if they have the same truth table, then they are (by definition) equivalent. Note that this means that statements that on the surface have nothing in common, and even when there is no mathematical way to transform one statement into the other, are still considered equivalent if their truth tables match up. Most executives that ask you to show that two statements are equivalent as an exercise, ask you to do it _without_ truth tables, because it's not very instructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, if they have the same truth table, then they are (by definition) equivalent. Note that this means that statements that on the surface have nothing in common, and even when there is no mathematical way to transform one statement into the other, are still considered equivalent if their truth tables match up.   – [Arthur](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631196/using-truth-tables-verify-that-the-contrapositive-and-original-statement-are-lo#comment3326126_1631196)